# Floating my button to the right is not working

Tags: html, css

I´m here with a strange situation, trying to float my button `input[type="submit"]` to the right.

I have space there and so I´m floating the button to the right to stand beside my input text.

But the float is not working and the button is not going, in any way, to the right.

**My jsfiddle with problem illustrated:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/5Nq2N/1/

**My Html:**

```
<footer id="footer-container">
    <section id="footer1">
      <div id="col">             
         <h1>NEWSLETTER</h1>
         <p>Register in our Newsletter.</p>

         <form action="" name="newsletter" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label id="email-label2">
             <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
             <input type="text"id="email2" name="email" placeholder="e-mail"  required/>
            </label>http://jsfiddle.net/#save
            <br />
            <label id="submit">
              <input type="hidden" name="news_register" value="register" />
              <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" src="" />
            </label>     
         </form>
     </div>
    </footer>
```

**My Css:**

```
#footer-container
{
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    background:brown; 
    height:auto;    
}

#footer1
{
    width:320px;
    margin:15px 10px 15px 10px;
    height:auto;    

}

#col
{
    float:left;
     margin-right:53px;

}

#col h1
{
    border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;
    font-family:'bariol_boldbold';
    color:#fff; 
    width:300px;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
}


#col p
{
    width:300px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:justify;
    color:#ccc; 
    font-size:14px; 
    font-family:'bariol_regularregular'; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}  



input[type="text"] 
{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 3px;

}

#email2 
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-indent:5px;
    width:172px;
    height:18px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family:'Tahoma';
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
}



input[type="submit"]
{
    float:right; 
    margin-right:5px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Tahoma';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    margin-top:10px;
    outline:none;
    background: blue; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
    width: 70px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #3c3412; 
    margin-bottom:15px;

}
```

Comment: Why are you floating everything? inputs are inline blocks by default, and will automatically appear next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the float, your layout looks like this:

```
/----------------Container------------------\
| [Text input here]                         |
| [Submit button here]                      |
\-------------------------------------------/
```

Now let's factor in the `float:right`:

```
/----------------Container------------------\
| [Text input here]                         |
|                      [Submit button here] |
\-------------------------------------------/
```

See how even though there's room, it's not magically moving up.

Now, let's try moving the submit button to be *before* the text input in your layout:

```
/----------------Container------------------\
| [Submit button here]                      |
| [Text input here]                         |
\-------------------------------------------/
```

Result with float:

```
/----------------Container------------------\
| [Text input here]    [Submit button here] |
\-------------------------------------------/
```

Yay! But... having the submit button *before* the text is not very semantic at all. What else can be done?

Well, you could try removing the `<br />` tag.

[image: result]

Adjust margins as needed!

Comment: Very good answer!! But I´m having some issues putting my button some pixels to top, to be align with the input text. Im trying input[type="submit"] {margin-bottom:5px;} but its not working!

Answer (score 3):

You had a couple of problems with the semantics and broken tags. I fixed it up and and updated the CSS: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5Nq2N/3/

Tips:

1. Don't place input fields inside label elements. Labels should describe the input field and sit above them. `<label for="email">Enter your email</label>`
2. Float the container with your items in it, the containers will stack against each other.
3. Clear your floats ;)
4. Read CSS Mastery by Andy Budd, its a great foundation.

[image]

```
<footer id="footer-container">
            <section id="footer1">
                <div id="col">             
                    <h1>NEWSLETTER</h1>
                    <p>Register in our Newsletter.</p>

                    <form action="" name="newsletter" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div id="email-label2">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                            <input type="text"id="email2" name="email" placeholder="e-mail"  required />
                        </div>

                        <div id="submit">
                            <input type="hidden" name="news_register" value="register" />
                            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>     
                     </form>
                </div>
           </section>
</footer>

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#footer-container
{
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    background:brown; 
    height:auto;    
}

#footer1
{
    width:320px;
    margin:15px 10px 15px 10px;
    height:auto;    

}

#col
{
    float:left;
     margin-right:53px;

}

#col h1
{
    border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;
    font-family:'bariol_boldbold';
    color:#fff; 
    width:300px;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
}


#col p
{
    width:300px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:justify;
    color:#ccc; 
    font-size:14px; 
    font-family:'bariol_regularregular'; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}  



input[type="text"] 
{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 3px;

}

#email2 
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-indent:5px;
    width:172px;
    height:18px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family:'Tahoma';
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    float: left;
}

#submit {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

input[type="submit"]
{
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Tahoma';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    outline:none;
    background: blue; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
    width: 70px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #3c3412; 
    margin-bottom:15px;

}
```

Comment: Thanks man! It was that I was trying But now Im having other problem because I want to push 2px to top my div #submit and its not working. Like this: #submit {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0px 2px 5px;
}